# Deserialize header to Pojo in Webflux?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, webflux

I have a header that's some encoded Json, so I have a POJO to deserialize it to.

How do I make Spring Boot auto deserialize it?

I've tried creating a `@Component Test implements Converter<String, MyPojo>` but it never gets called. The one example I found was for WebMvc.